# Django's Inline Admin: a 'pre-filled' field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm working on my first Django project, in which I want a user to be able to **create custom forms, in the admin, and add fields to it** as he or she needs them. For this, I've added a reusable app to my project, found on github at:

> https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder

I'm having trouble, because **I want to make it so 1 specific field is 'default' for every form** that's ever created, because it will be necessary in every situation (by the way my, it's irrelevant here, but this field corresponds to a point on the map).

An important section of code from this django-forms-builder app, showing the use of **admin.TabularInline**:

```
#admin.py
#...
class FieldAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Field
    exclude = ('slug', )


class FormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formentry_model = FormEntry
    fieldentry_model = FieldEntry

    inlines = (FieldAdmin,)
#...
```

So my question is: **is there any simple way to add default (already filled fields) for an admin 'TabularInline' in the recent Django versions?** If not possible, I would really appreciate a pointer to somewhere I could learn how to go about solving this.

Important: I've searched for similar questions here and even googled the issue. **I've found some old questions** (all from 2014 or way older) **that mention this possibility not being directly provided by Django**. The answers involved somewhat complex/confusing suggestions, given that I'm a Django begginer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

**1: Set a default on the field in the model.**

Django's dynamic admin forms and inlines are smart enough to detect this and display it automatically as a default choice or entry.

```
class Book(models.Model):

    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**2: Use a custom form in your TabularInline class.**

```
class BookInlineForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('rating', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = kwargs.pop('initial', {})
        # add a default rating if one hasn't been passed in
        initial['rating'] = initial.get('rating', 0)
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(BookInlineForm, self).__init__(
            *args, **kwargs
        )


class BookTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    form = BookInlineForm


class ShelfAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BookAdmin,)
```

Comment: This only partially solved my problem (I wanted only 1 of the inlines to be pre-filled and not all of them), but the 2nd idea you gave definitely got me on the right track, therefore I'm accepting your answer. Worth noting that instead of 'models.Form' I used 'forms.ModelForm' (needing from django import forms). Also in the 'class Meta' I've added fields = '__all__' because I got an error saying either 'fields' or 'exclude' are necessary for correct functioning. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer for the use of ModelForm. Glad this helped!

Comment: What is typical use case for allowing users to create their own admin forms ?

Comment: The admin user might want to deploy different forms as he/she needs to. Dynamic form building in the admin would allow them to do so easily, without needing any 'developer help'

Answer (score 0):

This is a **simple possbile way** to add `default(per-filled) data` in Django admin panel for **InlineModelAdmin**

```
class FieldAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Field
    fields = ('type', 'amount')

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.form.base_fields['amount'].initial = 20
        return formset
```