# Django - Custom values for inline list item field

Tags: django

After searching for a while, I can't seem to find any answer for this so I'm asking this question. What I want to is display some values based on a person's salary and a bracket. My models looks like this.

```
class Employee
    salary = models.DecimalField

class Benefit
    some_fields

class EmployeeBenefit
    employee = models.ForeignKey
    benefit = models.ForeignKey

class BenefitVersion
    benefit = models.ForeignKey

class BenefitBracket
    benefit_version = models.ForeignKey
    from_salary = models.DecimalField
    to_salary = models.DecimalField
    the_fields_I_want_to_display
```

As you can see it's quite deep, there would be a bunch of querying to do to get to the fields I want.

I basically need to get the employee's salary(which is easy because this is gonna be inside EmployeeAdmin) then get the current benefit of the `EmployeeBenefit` list item, then based on the benefit and the employee's salary, get the bracket and then display some of it's fields on the `inline`.

I want to display the `the_fields_I_want_to_display` on the `admin.TabularInline` for `EmployeeBenefit` inside my `EmployeeAdmin`. I was testing using a `forms.ModelForm` in the `inline` and modifying it's contents using `get_form` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581522/djangos-inline-admin-a-pre-filled-field) answer but django is not calling `get_form`. I also previously tried using `calculated_fields` but it's not being rendered as well.

I'm using django 3.1.7 btw

Edit:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24462173/10464730) and try it out right now. I think it has potential but unfortunately the `obj` that `get_formset` gives is `Employee` so I still need to find a way to get the right `EmployeeBenefit` for the list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I already figured out a way to do this. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223856/10464730) SO answer, I got an idea on how I should receive the data I passed to the formset using `get_formset`.

So, in my `get_formset`, I did something like this.

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    formset = super(Inline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
    formset.request = request
    benefit_details_dict_arr = []

    emp_contribs = models.EmployeeBenefit.objects.filter(employee=obj)
    #because what I'm getting here is Employee and not a EmployeeBenefit, I have to query it first

    for contrib in emp_contribs:
        bracket = contrib.get_benefit_bracket(datetime.now())
        benefit_details_dict_arr.append({
            "key": bracket.val,
            "key2": bracket.val2,
        })

    formset.benefit_details = benefit_details_dict_arr

    return formset
```

Then on the formset, I receive the data this way.

```
class EmpBenefitFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = models.EmployeeBenefit

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmpBenefitFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        cntr = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            init_data = self.benefit_details[cntr]

            for field in form.fields:
                if field in init_data:
                    form.initial[field] = init_data[field]

                    form.fields[field].required = False
                    form.fields[field].disabled = True

            cntr += 1
```

Also, if you're gonna use this way of receiving the data, each field you want to inflate should be declared on the `fields` of the inline. This should work if the fields you want to set an initial value are actual fields of the model. You might need to tweak this a bit to work for custom fields